# How can I create a counter as components to use multiple times and create one button to reset all the counter in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create a counter component to use multiple times and I want to create a button component or a button in the app.js to reset all the components. So I created the counter component, but I do not understand how to create the button. I created an individual reset button for each component. But I can not create the reset button which will be reset everything. I tried in many ways, but I failed.

Here is my counter component:

```
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import Button from './Button';
import ShowCount from './ShowCount';

export default function ReactCounter({num}) {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    const resetCounter = () => {
        setCount(0);
    };

    const incrementByOne = useCallback(() => {
        setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + num);
    }, [num])

    return (
        <div className="app">
            <ShowCount count={count} title = "Counter 1" />
            <Button handleClick={incrementByOne}>Increment By One</Button>
            <Button handleClick={resetCounter}>Reset</Button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is the app.js file:

```
import ReactCounter from './components/ReactMeth';
import Title from './components/Title';

export default function App() {
    
    return (
        <div className="app">
            <Title />
            <ReactCounter num={10} />
            <ReactCounter num={2} />
            <ReactCounter num={1} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

And here is the other components:

ShowCount.js

```
import React from 'react';

function ShowCount ({count, title}) {
    console.log(`rendering ${title}...`);
    
    return(
        <p>
            {title}: {count}
        </p>
    )
}

export default React.memo(ShowCount);
```

Button.js

```
import React from 'react'

function Button({handleClick, children}) {
  return (
    <p>
        <button type='button' onClick={handleClick}>
            {children}
        </button>
    </p>
  )
}

export default React.memo(Button)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a useState to controll when to reset all the fields. This is one way to do it which is pretty basic, but does the job.
It is just a useState which is connected to all the counters, and each time it changes value (which will happend when clicken on the 'reset all' button on linje 12 in App.js), the counters will use a useEffect and trigger a reset of their counter.

ReactCounter.js

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Button from "./Button";
import ShowCount from "./ShowCount";

export default function ReactCounter({ num, reset }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const resetCounter = () => {
    setCount(0);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(0);
  }, [reset]);

  const incrementByOne = useCallback(() => {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + num);
  }, [num]);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <ShowCount count={count} title="Counter 1" />
      <Button handleClick={incrementByOne}>Increment By One</Button>
      <Button handleClick={resetCounter}>Reset</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactCounter from "./components/ReactCounter";

export default function App() {
  const [resetAll, setResetAll] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <ReactCounter num={10} reset={resetAll} />
      <ReactCounter num={2} reset={resetAll} />
      <ReactCounter num={1} reset={resetAll} />
      <button onClick={() => setResetAll(resetAll === 1 ? 0 : 1)}>
        reset all
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I want to know, is there any other way to do this? like using context API or another way? I do not need code, I just need the method. Because passing the 'reset' through the useEffect's dependency is not a good practice I think.